# ¿Mostrar elementos de un array mediante una cadena de texto en html?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array con varios objetos los cuales quiero mostrar en un contenedor; sí tengo noción de como mostrar/imprimir en pantalla el contenido de cada objeto, sin embargo tengo problemas ya que estoy tratando de armar una cadena para pasarle al contenedor mediante el `innerHTML()`.

Ya tengo la estructura de todo y puedo visualizar cada objeto en la consola; lo siguiente es lo que tengo en javascript.

```
let rela = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("relacionados"));
let html = ' ';
for (let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++) {         
     console.log(rela[i]);
    //******* 
    // html += '<div class="item"><img class="trj_img_cls" src="${rela[i].foto}" alt="${rela[i].nombre}" id="${rela[]i.categoria} . , . ${rela[i].subcategoria}';
    //*******
}
//*******
// document.getElementById('contenedorR').innerHTML = html;
//*******
```

El problema es dentro del bucle al armar el contenido de la variable html ya que he tratado de utilizar `${...}`, es decir, el símbolo "`" seguido de los corchetes pero y sin obviar que debo finalizar la cadena antes de que desee usar lo ya mencionado y luego de haber ocupado el "'`${...}`'" pero en el editor toda la variable se me muestra como una sola cadena (como que si no hubiese finalizado y empezado con el '; también otro problema me da al armar el atributo id ya que como se observar no solo tiene un elemento.

**Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este inconveniente para poder lograr que después se pueda agregar con el `innerHTML()`?**

**También quisiera saber como se puede utilizar el `.toFixed()` en la parte del atributo id en caso de que se requiera mostrar un valor con 2 decimales.**

Comment: El problema es que estas usando comillas simples (`'`) cuando deberias usar comillas invertidas (`\``). [Mas info acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). También te falta cerrar los tags `img` y `div`

Comment: Lo de cerrar las etiquetas si tienes razón y aparte encontré un sitio que habla de esto y básicamente dice que solo se utiliza backtiks  al comienzo y fin de la cadena y lo demás como comillas dobles y simples se las borra; ya voy a poner una respuesta a mi pregunta donde pondré el link del sitio donde ví lo que te estoy comentando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue que en la variable html adentro del bucle la iguale con backtiks a las comillas simples las borré.

el código quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
let rela = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("relacionados"));
let html = ' ';
for (let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++) {         
     console.log(rela[i]); 
    html += `<div class="item"><img class="trj_img_cls" src="${rela[i].foto}" alt="${rela[i].nombre}" id="${rela[]i.categoria} . , . ${rela[i].subcategoria}"></div>`;
}
document.getElementById('contenedorR').innerHTML = html;
```

Esto lo pude hacer al leer un articulo sobre las backtiks; el enlace es: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/03/26/backticks-javascript-plantillas-cadenas/

Lo que todavía no he logrado hacer que también me funcione es el `.toFixed()` en caso de aumentar en el atributo "id" `${rela[i].valor}`, intente:

```
1) ${rela[i].valor}.toFixed(2)

2) ${rela[i].valor.toFixed(2)}
```

resultados:

1. me aparecía en consola 99.toFixed(2)
2. no se retornaba algún valor ni algún elemento del array

Estoy probando también `number_format()`